# Socket.io 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, sockets, express

I have this piece of code on my server

```
    var express = require('express');
    var routes = require('./routes');
    var user = require('./routes/user');
    var http = require('http');
    var path = require('path');

var app = express();
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    server.listen(3000);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      console.log("Socket connected");
    });
```

I just want to create a connection

and on the client -

```
<script src="public/javascripts/socket.io.js"></script>
     <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
     </script>
```

And when I open my browser I get this error in console:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1404410309733 400 (Bad Request) socket.io.js:1659
XHR finished loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/1/?t=1404410309733".
```

I've already done this like 10 times and I never get this. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you have any proxy set on your computer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think an older version of `socket-io` could be the reason.

I was getting this problem when I was using `0.9.16` version. I upgraded to following and it worked.

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js"></script>
```