# socket.io: bad request error at high trafic

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

when I run my socket.io chat application with high load (+500 connections), I receive that error

```
webSocket connection to 'ws://myIp:1400/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=GLQPwRHTgJCN9lFhAAoO' failed: 
Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
socket.io.js:95 GET http://myIp:1400/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1437426459994-177&sid=GLQPwRHTgJCN9lFhAAoO
 400 (Bad Request)17.Request.create @ socket.io.js:95Request @ socket.io.js:9017.XHR.request @ socket.io.js:9017.XHR.doPoll @ socket.io.js:9018.Polling.poll @ socket.io.js:10718.Polling.onData @ socket.io.js:109(anonymous function) @ socket.io.js:909.Emitter.emit @ socket.io.js:3517.Request.onData @ socket.io.js:9617.Request.onLoad @ socket.io.js:10217.Request.create.xhr.onreadystatechange @ socket.io.js:94
chat.js.php:204 Error: xhr poll error
    at XHR.14.Transport.onError socket.io.js:9017.XHR.request @ socket.io.js:9017.XHR.doWrite @ socket.io.js:90(anonymous function) @ socket.io.js:110(anonymous function) @ socket.io.js:183proxy @ socket.io.js:218(anonymous function) @ socket.io.js:183(anonymous function) @ socket.io.js:18225.exports.encodePacket @
```

I tried to use **pm2 module** but does not help.

Any idea on how to fix that ?

Comment: Are you using clusters? or mean.io?

Comment: Which operating system? If Linux what max open files limit (`ulimit -n`)?

Comment: I dont use clusters. I dont use mean.io.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560480/socket-io-400-bad-request

Answer (score 0):

Cluster module doesn't play well with Socket.io 1.x

https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/637